# Choose the branch for $(1-\zeta^2)^{1/2}$ that makes it holomorphic in the upper half-plane and positive when $-1<\zeta<1$

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-cuts

From Stein/Shakarchi's *Complex Analysis* page 232:

> ...We consider for $z\in \mathbb{H}$, $$f(z)=\int_0^z
>  \frac{d\zeta}{(1-\zeta^2)^{1/2}},$$ where the integral is taken from
>   $0$ to $z$ along any path in the closed upper half-plane. We choose
>   the branch for $(1-\zeta^2)^{1/2}$ that makes it holomorphic in the
>   upper half-plane and positive when $-1<\zeta<1$. As a result,
>   $$(1-\zeta^2)^{-1/2}=i(\zeta^2-1)^{-1/2}\quad \text{when }\zeta>1.$$

I'm a little confused on the branch they're choosing. Do they mean that the we cut along $\mathbb{R}\setminus [-1,1]$? But then $(\zeta^2-1)^{-1/2}$ is undefined for $\zeta>1$...

Comment: Since the whole question plays in the upper half plane, the cut is along the full x axis. To get to the mentioned real points, cut along some rays extending into the negative half plane like $\pm1-i\mathbb R_+$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A good way to think about powers is through the logarithm
$$
      (1-\zeta^{2})^{1/2} = e^{\frac{1}{2}\log(1-\zeta^{2})}.
$$
Wherever the logarithm is holomorphic, so is $(1-\zeta^{2})^{-1/2}$. Wherever the logarithm is real, the square root is real and positive. Logarithm of $f(z)=(1-z^{2})$ is done using an integral of $f'(z)/f(z)$. In this case,
$$
                  \log(1-\zeta^{2})=\int_{0}^{\zeta}\frac{-2z}{1-z^{2}}\,dz.
$$
The only trick in designing the logarithm is to restrict the domain so that you cannot circle a point where there is a non-zero residue. So the definition of the above works just fine, so long as you choose *any* path from 0 to $\zeta$ along a path which does cross the real axis on $(-\infty,-1]$ or on $[1,\infty)$. That's how branch cuts are handled. Branch cuts can be along just about any curve you like, chosen to make sure you *cannot* circle the places where the integrand has non-zero residues. Then
$$
      (1-\zeta^{2})^{1/2} = \exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\zeta}\frac{2z}{1-z^{2}}dz\right\}=\exp\left\{\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\zeta}\frac{1}{z-1}+\frac{1}{z+1}\,dz\right\}.
$$
You can see that this function is positive and real on the real axis $(-1,1)$ because the integral reduces to one on the real line where the integrand is real. Furthermore, function is discontinuous across the real axis on $(-\infty,1]$ by a multiplicative constant equal to $\exp\{\frac{1}{2}(-2\pi i)\}=-1$ because of the residue of $\frac{1}{1+z}$ at $z=-1$.

Comment: Thank you! In the second paragraph, did you mean "...cross the real axis on $(-\infty, -1)$ or on..."? You wrote "$1$". (A similar thing is in the last paragraph).

Comment: @Eric Auld: Thank for for that correction. I fixed that typo in the answer now.

Comment: So then how are they defining the function at $\zeta>1$? These points are removed from the domain, right? Or it is defined there, but discontinuous, perhaps?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, my mistake, it is only defined for $z\in \mathbb{H}$.

Comment: @Eric Auld: I should remove $-1$ and $1$ from the discussion, just to keep an open domain with the log is holomorphic, and then extend by continuity above and below the branch and at $\pm 1$. That's worth noting.

Comment: I like your method of thinking about powers. Tell me: you know the case where we make a branch cut between two finite points $z_1$ and $z_2$ so we can define $\sqrt{(z-z_1)(z-z_2)}$? How is there no residue in this case when we go once around the cut?

Comment: I think I actually get this, because $$\frac{1}{(z-z_1)(z-z_2)}=C\left( \frac{1}{z-z_1} - \frac{1}{z-z_2} \right),$$so the residues will cancel.

Comment: @Eric Auld: If you choose a branch cut of a segment between the two points $z_1$ and $z_2$, then you you won't have a problem because any closed path integral of $1/(z-z_1)+1/(z-z_2)$ is either 0 or an integer multiple of $4\pi i$. So the square root still works in that case as $e^{1/2(4\pi i)}=1$. This is an extension of the result to specific powers.

Comment: @Eric Auld: I forgot to mention: think logarithmic derivative $f'(z)/f(z)$. So you get $1/(z-z_1)+1/(z-z_2)$ for the integrand.

Comment: One more question:  In the OP it refers to $$(1-\zeta^2)^{-1/2}=i(\zeta^2-1)^{-1/2}$$ for $\zeta>1$. If we look at the argument of $(1-\zeta)(1+\zeta)$, it seems like it should change by $\pi$ when we go by $\zeta=1$, and change again by $\pi$ as we go by $\zeta=-1$. Therefore it is changing by $2\pi$ total...halve that and you get $\pi$, apply the exponential and you get a factor of $-1$. So why is the factor $i$?

Comment: That's why I was careful to say "multiplicative constant". If the jump in the exponent integral across the branch cut is $\pi i$, then the multiplicative factor is $-1$. That is, if you take the limits of the function from each side of the cut, then you end up with one value at a point on the branch being $-1$ times the other value, regardless of what that value may be. You can morph that branch cut curve to something other than a straight line, and the multiplicative constant across that branch cut will be the same (provided the morphing doesn't allow the branch to move across a branch point)

Comment: If we think of it as two cuts that we're putting together, is it fine to define the branch of $\arg(z-1)$ as being $0$ when $z-1$ is a negative real number? (That way added with the (normal) branch of $\arg(z+1)$ we get a positive number when $z\in (-1,1)$.

Comment: @Eric Auld: Consider the combinations when you have 3 roots and cube roots. Either design the domain to be simply connected, or so that the sum of the residues is a multiple of $6\pi i$. This gets tough to see without knowing how to build a logarithm to order, especially when the three singularities are not on a line.

Comment: @Eric Auld: I noticed you are at Courant. I knew Richard Courant's grandson, Ted, while in school. Ted was a true Gentleman; I was particularly amused when he told about what a treat it was to visit his Grandfather's house in Manhattan when he was growing up (yes, a house!) I noticed that there is a short wikipedia page on Ted.

Comment: Interesting...I had no idea his grandson was in mathematics. It says the man went to Berkeley and Reed...did you know him at Berkeley? I used to live next to Reed college. Had some interesting roommates...

Answer (score 1):

Another (probably not as good) way to look at it is to think
$$
\sqrt{1-\zeta^2} = i \sqrt{\zeta -1} \sqrt{\zeta + 1} 
$$
Choose the (possibly different) branches for each of the square roots on the right side to give you what you need. It might look at first like you will have problems on $z \in [-1,1]$, but the discontinuities cancel each other.

For example, use the principle branch of $\sqrt{w}$ on $\zeta - 1$, but for $\zeta + 1$ use the branch of $\sqrt{w}$ where $-2\pi < \arg(w) < 0$.

**EDIT:**
Use $-2 \pi \le \arg(\zeta+1) < 0$ and $-\pi < \arg(\zeta -1) \le \pi$.
Then $-\pi \le \arg(\sqrt{\zeta+1}) < 0$ and $-\pi/2 < \arg(\sqrt{\zeta -1}) \le \pi/2$.

So on $-1 < z < 1$ you get
$$
\arg(i \sqrt{\zeta -1} \sqrt{\zeta + 1} ) = \pi/2 + (-\pi) + \pi/2 = 0
$$
On $1 < z$ you get
$$
\arg(i \sqrt{\zeta -1} \sqrt{\zeta + 1} ) = \pi/2 + (-\pi) + 0 = -\pi/2
$$
so
$$
\arg(\frac{1}{i \sqrt{\zeta -1} \sqrt{\zeta + 1}} ) = \pi/2 = \arg(\frac{i}{\sqrt{t^2-1}})
$$
where $t = |\zeta| > 1$ and $\sqrt{t^2-1}$ uses the regular square root on $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: Can you explain why the factor is $i$? It seems to me like the argument of $(1-\zeta)(1+\zeta)$ should differ by $2\pi$ between $\zeta<1$ and $\zeta>1$. Then taking half of that, and applying the exponential would give us a factor of $-1$ between the two locations.

Comment: @EricAuld: Note that I'm taking the root of $\zeta - 1$ instead of $1-\zeta$. Just easier for me to think of it that way. That's where the factor of $i$ comes from.

Comment: Hmm...sorry, I'm still not understanding. In the OP it refers to $$(1-\zeta^2)^{-1/2}=i(\zeta^2-1)^{-1/2}$$ for $\zeta>1$. If we look at the argument of $(1-\zeta)(1+\zeta)$, it seems like it should change by $\pi$ when we go by $\zeta=1$, and change again by $\pi$ as we go by $\zeta=-1$. Therefore it is changing by $2\pi$ total...halve that and you get $\pi$, apply the exponential and you get a factor of $-1$. So why is the factor $i$?

Comment: See the **edit**. The point is that in this method (which isn't as nice as the method in the other answer), you think of $\sqrt{\zeta^2-1}$ as the product of two functions, and use a different branch of the square root on each linear factor. Hope that helps.