# Stein complex analysis example 8.4.2

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

> Consider for $z\in\Bbb H$,
> $$f(z) = \int_0^z{d\zeta\over (1-\zeta^2)^{1/2}},$$
> where the integral is taken from $0$ to $z$ along any path in the closed upper half-plane. *We choose the branch for $(1-\zeta^2)^{1/2}$ that makes it holomorphic in the upper half-plane and positive when $-1<\zeta<1$. As a result,
> $$(1-\zeta^2)^{-1/2} = i(\zeta^2-1)^{-1/2}\quad\text{when}\ \zeta>1.$$*

I don't understand how the branch is chosen. I know that if we choose a branch $(-\infty,1]$ for $\sqrt{1-\zeta}$ (so that $0\leq \arg\log<2\pi$ on this branch) and $(-\infty,-1]$ for $\sqrt{1+\zeta}$ (so that $-\pi\leq\arg\log<\pi$ on this branch) then $(1-\zeta^2)^{1/2}$ is holomorphic on $\Bbb C\setminus[-1,1]$. I can say $(1-\zeta^2)^{1/2}$ is positive on $-1<\zeta<1$ with this branch but can't understand the displayed equality for $\zeta>1$.
For $\zeta>1$ then
\begin{align*}
(1-\zeta)^{-1/2} & = \exp\left(-{1\over 2}\log(1-\zeta)\right)\\
& = \exp\left(-{1\over 2}\left(\ln|1-\zeta|+i\arg(1-\zeta)\right)\right)\\
& = \exp\left(-{1\over 2}(\ln|\zeta-1|+i\arg(\zeta-1)+\pi i)\right)\\
& = \exp\left(-{\pi i\over 2}-{1\over 2}\log(\zeta-1)\right)\\
& = -i(\zeta-1)^{-1/2},\\
\end{align*}
and $(1+\zeta)^{-1/2} = (\zeta+1)^{-1/2}$ so I conclude
$$(1-\zeta^2)^{-1/2} = (1+\zeta)^{-1/2}(1-\zeta)^{-1/2} = -i(\zeta+1)^{-1/2}(\zeta-1)^{-1/2} = -i(\zeta^2-1)^{-1/2}.$$
Could you please point out the error?

N.B. I already know there is [a post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/626256/668308) asking the same example.

Answer (score 1):

I will use $w$ instead of $\zeta$ for easy typing.
Below some domains will appear, rays (closed half-lines) are removed from $\Bbb C$ to define them. So it may be useful to have a notation for such rays.
Let $R^+_a$ be the ray $[a,\infty)$.
Let $R^-_a$ be the ray $(-\infty, a]$.

---

Start with $w\in \Bbb H$, so $w$ is in the upper half plane (notation), and $w^2$ is in the domain $D^+_0:=\Bbb C-R^+_0$.

Then $-w^2$ is in the domain $D^-_0 :=\Bbb C-R^-_0$.

Then $1-w^2$ is in the domain $D^-_1:=\Bbb C-R^-_1$.
So we eliminate from $\Bbb C$ the ray $R^-_1=(-\infty,1]$, which is the union of $(-\infty,0)$ and $\{0\}$ and $(0,1]$. At the next step we apply the bijection $z\to 1/z$ of $\Bbb C^\times$, so we land in $\Bbb C$ without the image of $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,1]$.

Then $1/(1-w^2)$ is in the domain $\Xi=\Bbb C - R^-_0 - R^+_1$,
which is the complex plane with a cut of $\Bbb C$ obtained by removing two half-lines, so that from the real axis there remains only the open interval $(0,1)$.

Now we have to take "some square root" from this expression, $1/(1-w^2)$, and have two chances. The choice is restricted by the imposed results for $w$-values which are real and between $-1$ and $1$, $w\in(-1,1)$.

Well, such values are not in $\Bbb H$, but at the boundary. So we insist to have only some continuity. Let us start with some $w\in(-1,1)$.
Then $w^2$ is real and between $0$ and $1$, $w\in[0,1)$, so $1-w^2\in(0,1]$, which is an element at the boundary of $D^-_1$. The inversion maps it to
$1/(1-w^2)\in[1,\infty)$, which is an element at the boundary of $\Xi$.

We extract the square root "as usual" (principal branch) from the real positive number $1/(1-w^2)\in[1,\infty)$, and it is clear how to continuously extend this to $D^-_1$.

---

Let's move the focus now on the question. We have to deal with a relation for some $w$ which is again **not in** $\Bbb H$. The relation uses on its L.H.S the expression $(1-w^2)^{1/2}$. I suppose it is this in detail constructed function on $D^-_1$. On the R.H.S. we have a new function, $i(w^2 -1)^{1/2}$. So one should invoke for this other function the same precision in explaining it. But fortunately, we need it only for real values of $w$, $w>1$, and in this case let us take
$(w^2 -1)^{1/2}=\sqrt{w^2 -1}$ based on the real square root function $\sqrt{\ \cdot \ }$ and furthermore even only for some very special values of $w$.
Because the relation to be shown has only two chances, given the discrete monodromy character of the involved functions:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{either }(1-w^2)^{-1/2} &= +i\cdot(w^2-1)^{-1/2}\ ,\\
\text{    or }(1-w^2)^{-1/2} &= -i\cdot(w^2-1)^{-1/2}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
So let us look closer at the relation that may hold for some very special value of $w$. I use $w=5/4$.

The R.H.S. in the above block is clear, it is $\displaystyle\pm i\cdot\frac 43$, and we closer look which is the matched sign from the L.H.S. - plus or minus.

For the L.H.S. we have the following explicitly displayed steps:
$$
\begin{aligned}
w &=\frac 54 \ ,\\
w^2 &=\frac {25}{16}\ ,\\
1-w^2 &=-\frac {9}{16}\ ,\\
\frac 1{1-w^2} &=-\frac {16}9\ ,\\
(1-w^2)^{-1/2} :=
\sqrt{\qquad\frac 1{1-w^2}\qquad}
&=\sqrt{-\frac {16}9}=+i\cdot \frac 43 \ .
\end{aligned}
$$
We get a plus sign.

---

The whole story made short: In the above computations we have two steps that do not commute, taking the inverse, and using the principal branch of the square root,
$$
\sqrt{\qquad\frac 1{1-w^2}\qquad}
\ne
\frac 1{\qquad\sqrt{1-w^2}\qquad}\ ,
$$
and some more propositions would may have been necessary in the referenced text to fix the difference.

Answer (score 0):

> For $\zeta>1$ then
> \begin{align*}
> (1-\zeta)^{-1/2} & = \exp\left(-{1\over 2}\log(1-\zeta)\right)\\
> & = \exp\left(-{1\over 2}\left(\ln|1-\zeta|+i\arg(1-\zeta)\right)\right)\\
> & = \exp\left(-{1\over 2}(\ln|\zeta-1|+i\arg(\zeta-1)+\pi i)\right)\\
> & = \exp\left(-{\pi i\over 2}-{1\over 2}\log(\zeta-1)\right)\\
> & = -i(\zeta-1)^{-1/2}\\
> \end{align*}

should be

> \begin{align*}
> (1-\zeta)^{-1/2} & = \exp\left(-{1\over 2}(\ln|\zeta-1|+i\arg(\zeta-1)    \color{red}{-}\pi i)\right)\\
> & = \exp\left(  \color{red}{+} {\pi i\over 2}-{1\over 2}\log(\zeta-1)\right)\\
> & = \color{red}{i}(\zeta-1)^{-1/2},\\
> \end{align*}

so we have $$
(1-\zeta^2)^{-1/2} = i(\zeta^2-1)^{-1/2}\quad \text{when 
 } \zeta>1.
$$

Comment: I guess that is because I chose the branch to be $0\leq\arg\log<2\pi$?

Comment: For $z\in \Bbb C\setminus (-\infty, 1]$, $\log z\,\,$  is defined as $\log|z|+i\arg z, -\pi <\arg z<\pi.$
Suppose $\zeta>1$ and let $z=\zeta+i\varepsilon $ $(\varepsilon >0)$, so that $z\in \Bbb H. $ Then $(1-z^2)\in \Bbb C\setminus (-\infty, 1]$.
Since $$
1-z^2=1-p^2+\varepsilon ^2-2i\pi \varepsilon,
$$ 
we know that $\arg (1-z^2)\to -\pi,\, \text{not }\, \pi$  ($\varepsilon \to +0$).
Hence $(1-\zeta^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}=\lim_{\varepsilon \to +0}(1-z^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}=
(\zeta^2-1)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\exp(i\pi/2)=i(\zeta^2-1)^{-\frac{1}{2}}.
$

Comment: EDIT. $$1-z^2=1-p^2+\varepsilon ^2-2i\pi \varepsilon$$ should be $$1-z^2=1-\zeta^2+\varepsilon ^2-2i\pi \varepsilon$$